# Windows versions of pretest releases

Tags: microsoft-windows, install

"Emacs pretest 26.1.92 is out!" reported a recent email. Are downloads of this available for the Windows platform? Where can I find them?

Files [here](https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/emacs-27/) were last updated on 17 January 2019, so presumably this is not the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Emacs 26.1.91 windows files are at https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/emacs-26/. I expect, that Emacs 26.1.92 windows will appear at the same directory; I have no idea when this will happen, though.

Comment: Thanks. The 26.1.92 files are there now.